# How to use Activerecord find([34,183]) with the conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In the Activerecord rails where we use `find[(a,b)]` to get all the rows that has ids between a and b. How to add condition to this function where we can match 'id' column with matching certain integer.

I tried below code but is not working.

```
User.find([34,183], :conditions => {:id => 4}).
```

Comment: You need to go with [where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) , as find doesn't accept second argument.

Comment: Why are you trying to find users with ids between 34 and 183 that have an id of 4? 4 isn't between 34 and 183, so you won't find any records that match that. I must be misunderstanding your question, but it's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. You can't have an ID of 4 which is between 34 and 183.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I would contend that this is __not__ a duplicate question. AFAIK, the OP is asking how to merge the results of two different queries. Though it might be irregularly worded, it seems to me a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [docs regarding range conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions):

```
User.where(id: 34..183)
```

This will generate the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (users.id BETWEEN '34' AND '183')
```

To append the results of *another* ActiveRecord `where` query, use the [`merge`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) method:

```
users = User.where(id: 34..183)
user = User.where(id: 4)

users.merge(user)
```

Comment: You could give him the final solution... `User.where(id:34..183).find(4)` OR `User.where(id:34..183).where(id: 4)`

Comment: @MrYoshiji why the second `where` needed ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit because it fits the requirements defined by the asker, and to show that you can easily chain as many where statements as you want

Comment: Thanks for your input, I didn't know that 4 was actually less than 34, @ArupRakshit ...

Comment: @zeantsoi I really don't understand, how that *chain* works still ? :(

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thank you all for writing in. This one really help me to fix the feature that I was working on for a while.@zeantsoi